# Are there any Apache Kafka consumer lag checker?

Tags: apache-kafka

My Kafka Consumers commit their offsets to Kafka(instead of Zookeeper), so I cannot use [Kafka Manager](https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager).

[Burrow](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow) is great, however, I cannot use Go in our production environment. :(

So I'm wondering are there any Apache Kafka consumer lag checker besides the above two? I Googled it but didn't find much useful information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Who would know that you're using Go if you present them with a binary. Say it's C++ :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use Remora https://github.com/zalando-incubator/remora. Its an application that can be deployed with your kafka

Comment: Please note the comment at Inspiration on the remora page. Maybe you doesn't want burrow anymore.

Comment: _Disclaimer_: Associated contributor

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the same but it can use to monitor lag.

https://github.com/quantifind/KafkaOffsetMonitor

[Topic position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgpf6.png)

Comment: I've heard this before, didn't know it has updated to support offsets stored in kafka. will try it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is also *records-lag-max* JMX metric available at every Kafka Consumer instance.

So you can monitor this one either directly form your application by accesing MBean Server or remotely.